# Why don't variables upload in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a program that tracks how many apples apples I have and takes an apple away when I eat one.

```
apples=3

while apples>0:
    try: 
        print("You have {} a left".format(apples))

        Action=input('Action:')
        if action == "eat":
            apples=apples-1
        else:
            print("invalid")
    except:
        pass
```

However this code doesn't update apples when I write eat as user input.

> You have 3 apples left
>   Action:eat
>   You have 3 apples left
>   Action:eat
>   You have 3 apples left
>   Action:eat
>   You have 3 apples left
>   Action:eat
>   You have 3 apples left

Comment: Please provide the snippet where eat is provided as user input too

Comment: Variable is defined as `Action` but used as `action`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you defined `Action` but tried to use `action` (the case matters!). Without the `try` and `except` you may have noticed that yourself. That's one reason you should (almost) never use a bare `except`. Always catch specific exceptions like `ValueError` and similar.

If I remove these and use this code, the exception is shown:

```
apples=3

while apples>0:
    print("You have {} a left".format(apples))

    Action=input('Action:')
    if action == "eat":
        apples=apples-1
    else:
        print("invalid")


# ...

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
      4     print("You have {} a left".format(apples))
      5     Action=input('Action:')
----> 6     if action == "eat":
      7         apples=apples-1
      8     else:

NameError: name 'action' is not defined
```

You may also need to `strip` the `input` because it sometimes contains a trailing newline:

```
apples=3

while apples > 0:
    print("You have {} apples left".format(apples))
    action=input('Action:')
    if action.strip() == "eat":  # here is the strip that removes all leading and trailing whitespaces
        apples=apples-1
    else:
        print("invalid")
```